# FlutterDriver: Use Android back button

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, dart

I have a mobile application for Android with multiple pages and currently try to write simple integration tests for it...

The issue is that my app only uses internal Android back gestures, I have no back button or something like this.

Is it somehow possible to tell the `FlutterDriver` to go one page back? (Simulate a android internal back button?) Something like this:

```dart
driver.goPageBack()
```

Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your Activity code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_ACTIVITY);
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;   //null check
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);   //show back button
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Flutter repo there is a test that simulates the hardware back button by sending a message over the platform channel like this:

```dart
final ByteData message = const JSONMethodCodec().encodeMethodCall(const MethodCall('popRoute'));
await ServicesBinding.instance!.defaultBinaryMessenger.handlePlatformMessage('flutter/navigation', message, (_) { });
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/6688e63f68ebba0919a5fe3c8f8432bd8a65f81b/packages/flutter/test/widgets/router_test.dart#L725-L726

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I could find is a package that is a back button interceptor that has a method `BackButtonInterceptor.popRoute()` for testing that emulates the back button press: https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor

Comment: Thank you, I will research this opportunity. Do you know of any way I could access the Flutter Navigator in an integration test?